# Is it possible to fadeIn incoming data using jQuery AJAX

Tags: ajax, jquery

I wonder if it's possible detect and fadeIn if it detects any new `<li>data</li>` coming from aspx, using jQuery AJAX. Mostly would be used for news commenting system, so other readers would see a new comment fading in when they read news, and how it would apply to codes below.

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'WebForm1.aspx',
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#Urunler").html(data);
                }
            });
    });
```

---

```
    <ul id="Urunler" runat="server">

    </ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you can't change the `webform1.aspx` file to return only the new `li` elements then you can do something like following -

your success function would be

```
var count = $("#Urunler").find('li').length;
var count1 = $(data).siblings().length;
if(count < count1){
  var startIndex = count;
  while(startIndex < count1){
    var li = $($(data).siblings()[startIndex++]).clone();
    li.hide();
    $("#Urunler").append(li).fadeIn();
  }
}
```

this checks the number of existing `li` elements inside the `ul` and checks that number with the total number of `li` returned by the data. if the returned number of `li` is greater, it appends those `li` one at a time to the `ul` and fades them in. I haven't checked the code myself, but this should give you an idea.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, because you're adding on to a list of elements, you'll want to use `appendTo` rather than `html`.

```
$(data).appendTo('#Urunler').hide().fadeIn();
```

When you use `html`, it will grab the entire `#Urunler` element and hide it, whereas `appendTo` allows you to only work with the data you've created.

Edit: Used append when meaning to use appendTo

Comment: You may see some content flash here, unlikely, but possible. Whenever I need to do something like this, I'll create the new `li` element, hide that, append the new content and then fade the whole thing in